# Angular Injector Error help >

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck on this task in my angular project for the passed 7 hours, hopefully some one can help.

Well I am trying to display data from the backend in a table using angular. In My JS file I have the following:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: 'list.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });


MyApp.factory('MyApp', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/myapp/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, MyApp) {
    $scope.items = MyApp.query();
};
```

I keep getting this error:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myApp

Afer looking at the error I thought I was missing something in my HTML file but I think I have defined everything in my HTML file like so:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Stylesheets/DS72StyleSheet.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

I have no clue whats wrong here can some please help?

Comment: Yes, well I just tried now , still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dependency to ngResource to your module definition:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"])...
```

Comment: Thank you .. I get an error sayin :Error: [$resource:badcfg] array

Comment: I think the order of your script files is wrong. You need to have the angular-resource.js and angular-route.js before your app.js.